# ASP.NET Style tag getting ignored on User Control

Tags: css, asp.net, styles

Just recently I found out that my screens were off because their respective style weren't rendered. Though the styles that are declared on the head are fine but not on the user controls. As an example:

```html
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Program.ascx.cs" Inherits="Program" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<style type="text/css">
.regStatus 
{
    width: 130px;
    float: right;
    line-height: 24px;
}
.dateFilter
{
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
}
div.labelOverride div
{
    display: inline !important;
}
</style>
```

I use telerik as well but not sure what happened to have it behave this way. If I put the style inline, it works, if I move the style to asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server"> on the page, it works. Any clue on why the style tag are being ignored only on IE though 10-? Firefox, Chrome and IE11 is fine. 
Also, the style above are not on the source either

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at page source when run in web browser? If yes, what did you saw?

Comment: I already mentioned that the style on the usercontrol doesn't exist in the page source.